# What is a "far cry"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

What is a *far cry*, and what is its origin?

Comment: For contextual examples: fairly decent modern Rush song http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S9uNxUI9ng

Comment: As opposed to the old song, "Travellin' Light", where Cliff Richard is "a hoot and a holler away from paradise"!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A *far cry* is literally a distance that is quite far to try to call across; in other words, a great distance. The term is used to compare two (usually abstract) things that are vastly different from one another, as in:

> Old English is a far cry from the English we speak today.

Answer (score 1):

The OED says *a far cry* is a very long distance and quotes Walter Scott's *Tales of My Landlord* (1819):

> One of the Campbells replied, ‘It is a far cry to Lochow’; a proverbial expression of the tribe, meaning that their ancient hereditary domains lay beyond the reach of an invading enemy.

They contrast it with the older *within cry*, meaning within calling distance, and quote William Lithgow's *Totall Discourse Trav.* (1632):

> Villages and Houses..each one was within cry of another.

You can read this text [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=41oj3JOOUAwC&pg=PA414&dq=%22within%20cry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gMvuUOaCEYOTtAa1y4CYDA&redir_esc=y).